# cyclic dependency while mapping Entity to DTO in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, circular-dependency, data-transfer-objects

I have two entity classes as:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Foo", schema="REF_DATA")
public class Foo {
 private Long fooId;
 private String fooName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo")
  @ToString.Exclude
 private List<Bar> bars;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Bar", schema="REF_DATA")
public class Bar  {
    private Long barId;
    private String barName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fooId")
    private Foo foo;
}
```

And their respective DTO's looks like:

```
public class FooDto {
 private Long fooId;
 private String fooName;
 @JsonIgnoreProperties("foo")
 private List<BarDto> bars;
}

public class BarDto  {
    private Long barId;
    private String barName;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("bars") //added to avoid the cyclic dependency
    private FooDto foo;
}
```

When user calls `/getAllData` we are returning the following DTO:

```
public class FooBar {
    List<FooDto> foo;
    List<BarDto> bars;
}
```

We are able to fetch data from the backend using the JPA but getting error while mapping Entity to Dto. Mapper code looks like:

```
public interface DomainToDtoMapper<E extends BaseEntity, D extends BaseDto> {

   D mapDomainToDto(E domain);
}

public class FooDomainToDtoMapper implements DomainToDtoMapper<Foo, FooDto> {
    @Override
    public FooDto mapDomainToDto(Foo domain) {
        FooDto fooDto = new FooDto();
        FooDto.setfooId(domain.getfooId());
        FooDto.setfooName(domain.getfooName());
        if (domain.getBars() != null) {
            BarDomainToDtoMapper barDomainToDtoMapper= new BarDomainToDtoMapper();
            fooDto.setBars(domain.getBars().stream()
                    .map(barDomainToDtoMapper::mapDomainToDto)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        return fooDto;
    }

}


public class BarDomainToDtoMapper implements DomainToDtoMapper<Bar, BarDto> {
    @Override
    public BarDto mapDomainToDto(Bar domain) {
        BarDto barDto = new BarDto();
        barDto.setBarId(domain.getBarId());
        barDto.setBarName(domain.getBarName());
        //works fine if we remove this If condition but Bar won't have Foo in final output
        if (domain.getFoo() != null) {
            FooDomainToDtoMapper fooDomainToDtoMapper= new FooDomainToDtoMapper();
            barDto.setFoo(domain.getFoo());
        }
        return barDto ;
    }

}
```

While Mapping `Bar` to `BarDto` we are getting StackOverflow error.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.jpmorgan.markets.dto.mapper.FooDomainToDtoMapper .mapDomainToDto(FooDomainToDtoMapper .java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.jpmorgan.markets.dto.mapper.BarDomainToDtoMapper .mapDomainToDto(BarDomainToDtoMapper .java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
```

Similarly we want to return Individual `BarDto` and `FooDto` if user requests them by Id. But the thing is that in the final output one must contain the other object.I tried adding `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` in entities, still getting the same error. Is it becuase of we're explicitly mapping entities to DTO rather than returning entities directly? Is there any better way of doing this without using anything like `Mapstruct`?

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` as used in the below in below code.

****Foo Entity****

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Foo", schema="REF_DATA")
public class Foo {
   private Long fooId;
   private String fooName;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo")
   @ToString.Exclude
   @JsonManagedReference
   private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

**Bar  Entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Bar", schema="REF_DATA")
public class Bar  {
    private Long barId;
    private String barName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fooId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Foo foo;
}
```

*Note: If still faced any problem then try removing `@JsonManagedReference` from `Foo` entity.

Comment: do you mean to say? I should be adding those annotations in DTOs? I have tried those, still getting StackOverflow errror. we're not directly serializing Entities to JSON, we have explicitly written Mapper for it